# networking in azure kubernetes services

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-aks

[Here in Azure AKS networking using kubenet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-kubenet) it is mentioned that IP address range for --dns-cidr, --service-cide and --docker-brige-ip range should be an address space that isn't in use elsewhere in your network environment. I have also created Vnet and this AKS should be in that vnet.

1. Does this mean, for DNS, Service and Docker bridge, IP address range should be different then VNet IP range?
2. Pod CIDR, can we have it different then VNet range? As I am using Kubenet pod IP will not be from Vnet subnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes, they should not overlap.
2. this is virtual pod ip address space, not the one they will get from your vnet (if you would be using Azure CNI). these would be the internal only kubernetes ip addresses. With kubenet they would get routed to the appropriate nodes with UDR and then the node would forward traffic to the appropriate pod.

Comment: so basically I need at least 6 CIDR for one environment. (Vnet, Subnet, Pod, DNS, Service, Docker Bridge)

Comment: yeah, but subnet is a subset of vnet, dns is a subset of service, for docker you can always use something completely different

Comment: i will be testing it, just to ask. can i have same IP address range for aks network profile docker-bridge, service, dns and pods for the aks in different resource group in same subscription. i assume these address range are internal to AKS. i am using kubenet network plugin in aks

Comment: yes, different AKS clusters can have these overlapping, but you wont be able to route traffic between them (using kubenet at least)

Comment: my purpose is to have different aks cluster for different env i.e. dev, test, prod. so might not need to do communication between aks clusters. Thanks for the help it had sorted things for me.

Comment: With Azure CNI networking, would the service cird be routed on the local subnet, say if you had a user route table of 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: sorry, can you raise a new question, theres just to many different things in the comments here